# dbpedia graphDB semantic DB

Tags: dbpedia, graphdb

I recently installed graphDB to store my ontology.  I want to get access to dbpedia to get information using graphDB with SPARQL query.  For example:

```
SELECT distinct ?airport ?label ?RR
WHERE {
        dbpedia:London geo-pos:lat ?latBase ;
                       geo-pos:long ?longBase .
        ?airport omgeo:nearby(?latBase ?longBase "50mi");
                 a dbp-ont:Airport ;
                 ff:preferredLabel ?label ;
                 om:hasRDFRank ?RR .
} ORDER BY DESC(?RR)
```

If I want to execute this query with graphDB what do I need to do?

Do I have to download the rdf file into my db?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: did you try downloading the rdf file into your db?

Comment: no i want to send query to dbpedia from graphDB , i want to get information from the web without storing it in my db .

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a misunderstanding on the purpose of Graphdb. Graphdb is triplestore database and the workbench(the web interface you are using) is just tool that send queries to the database. This has the consequence that for example omgeo:nearby is a special predicate (think vendor extension) which is not part of standard query language and works in GraphDB only.

If you don't want to store the data in your database and query external stores(sparql endpoints), you can use federated sparql queries. Check the spec https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-federated-query/#simpleService for more info.